# Is it possible to differentiate the curve of the factorial function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers, factorial

It's pretty much summed it up in the title, but to be more specific I mean only the positive side of the x-axis(or at least maybe).

Maybe if we were looking for the negative axis, what would we be doing? Plot the graph in an argand plane? but that would put all positive factorials in the x-axis with only negative integers having any imaginary value

Comment: Look up _gamma function_.

Comment: The factorial is only defined for nonnegative integers, so it does not have a "curve". As mentioned above, its extension, the Gamma function, has a derivative.